# Unique rows from PostgreSQL database and ordering

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, distinct

how can I get unique rows from PostgreSQL (8.4.20), at this moment my query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT ON(student.id) student.id, 
    student.*,
    programme_stage.*
FROM  
    person AS student 
INNER JOIN 
    programme ON (student.id = programme.person_id) 
RIGHT JOIN 
    programme_stage ON (programme.id = programme_stage.programme_id) 
ORDER BY 
    student.id, 
    student.last_name ASC, 
    student.first_name ASC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

The above query works correctly, but I want to sort by the last and first name in first order.

Sample data:

```
| id | first_name | last_name | programme_id | programme_stage _id |
|----|------------|-----------|--------------|---------------------|
| 1  | Michał     | Nowak     | 1            | 1                   |
| 2  | Jan        | Kowalski  | 2            | 2                   |
| 3  | Tomasz     | Thomas    | 2            | 1                   |
```

Expected output:

```
| id | first_name | last_name | programme_id | programme_stage _id |
|----|------------|-----------|--------------|---------------------|
| 2  | Jan        | Kowalski  | 2            | 2                   |
| 1  | Michał     | Nowak     | 1            | 1                   |
| 3  | Tomasz     | Thomas    | 2            | 1                   |
```

If I try to remove from order statment student.id column, I getting error:

```
..SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match the expressions .. ORDER BY LINE 2:  DISTINCT ON(student_person.id) student_person.id, 
                 ^
```

Comment: Are you really still using 8.4? That has been out of support for many years now

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: What if you remove `student.id` from the `ORDER BY` clause?

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.id) s.*, ps.*
      FROM programme_stage ps LEFT JOIN
           programme p
           ON programme.id = ps.programme_id LEFT JOIN
           person s
           ON s.id = p.person_id)
      ORDER BY s.id
      LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
     ) s
ORDER BY s.last_name ASC, s.first_name ASC;
```

Notes:

- I prefer shorter table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.
- I prefer `LEFT JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`.  However, because you are using the `person` table for aggregation, you probably want inner joins.
- There is no need to select the `id` twice.
- You may need to select explicit columns instead of `*` if columns have the same name.

Comment: I have about 50 00 rows and your example, sort only first 10 (from subquery) :/

Comment: @JohnTemp . . . The `limit 10` is in *your* code.  If you want all rows, then remove it.

Comment: I want to sort alphabetically all rows (50 000) and after this get first 10 unique records. In your example, ten first rows are taken first and only them are being sorted.

Comment: @JohnTemp . . . The inner join sorts by `s.id`, which is what your query does.  Change the `order by` keys to be what you want.